# Reduce list of tuples to a single tuple in scala

Tags: scala, tuples

Item is a custom type.
I have a Iterable of pairs `(Item, Item)`. The first element in every pair is the same, so I want to reduce the list to a single pair of type `(Item, Array[Item])`

// `list: Iterable[(Item, Item)]`

// First attempt

```
val res = list.foldLeft((null, Array[Item]()))((p1,p2) => {
          (p2._1, p1._2 :+ p2._2)
}
```

// Second attempt

```
val r = list.unzip
val res = (r._1.head, r._2.toArray))
```

**1.** I don't know how to correctly setup the zero value in the first ("foldLeft") solution. Is there any way to do something like this?

**2.** Other than the second solution, is there a better way to reduce a list of custom object tuples to single tuple ?

Comment: `(list.head._1, list.map(_._2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure the first element in every pair is the same, why don't you use that information to simplify?

```
(list.head._1, list.map(_._2))
```

should do the work

if there are other cases where the first element is different, you may want to try:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (common, lst) => (common, lst.map(_._2)) }
```